# Green card in different states

Tags: usa, greencard

Does it differ from state to state in case of a green card holder. like different states have different laws pertaining to what a green card holder can get in case of medicare or medicaid. Some one told me that if you are in a republican state the laws are stricter than democrats where you get access to some government services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the requirements for Medicare are the same for all states.

The requirements for Medicaid do differ between states. For one, some states have expanded Medicaid for the Affordable Care Act, and some states haven't. Those that have expanded Medicaid allow all low-income US citizens and certain aliens up to 133% of poverty level, whereas those that haven't expanded Medicaid only allow people up to 100% of poverty level, and may have certain additional restrictions depending on state (e.g. not allowing working-age adults with no children and no disabilities). In addition, most states do not allow permanent residents (green card holders) on Medicaid for the first 5 years, but a few states don't have such a waiting period.

Some other benefits also have differences between states.